# Proving the area of a triangle within a triangle

Tags: proof-writing, vectors, area

Consider a triangle with vertices ABC, we pick a point C' on the line segment AB in such a way that |BC'|=2|AC'|. Similarly, we pick a point B' on the line segment AC and a point A' on the line segment BC, with |AB'|=2|CB'| and |CA'|=2|BA'|.

Draw the lines AA', BB', CC'. Prove the area of the little triangle that appears is 1/7 of the area of triangle ABC.

I've drawn the diagrm, however I still have got no idea how to prove this

Comment: See [Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh's_theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D,E,F$ be the intersection point between $AA'$ and $BB'$, $BB'$ and $CC'$, $CC'$ and $AA'$ respectively.

Then, note that
$$\frac{[\triangle{DEF}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}=\frac{[\triangle{ACA'}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}\times\frac{[AB'A']}{[\triangle{ACA'}]}\times\frac{[\triangle{DFB'}]}{[\triangle{AB'A'}]}\times\frac{[\triangle{DEF}]}{[\triangle{DFB'}]}$$$$=\frac{A'C}{BC}\times\frac{AB'}{AC}\times\frac{DF}{AA'}\times \frac{DE}{DB'}=\frac 49\times\frac{DF}{AA'}\times \frac{DE}{DB'}\tag1$$

So, all you need is to find $\frac{DF}{AA'}$ and $\frac{DE}{DB'}$.

You can use vector here (can you?), but using Menelaus' theorem should be easier :

For $\triangle{ABA'}$ and $CC'$, 
$$\frac{BC}{CA'}\cdot\frac{A'F}{FA}\cdot\frac{AC'}{C'B}=1\Rightarrow \frac{A'F}{FA}=\frac 43.$$

For $\triangle{A'AC}$ and $BB'$,
$$\frac{CB}{BA'}\cdot\frac{A'D}{DA}\cdot\frac{AB'}{B'C}=1\Rightarrow \frac{A'D}{DA}=\frac 16.$$

So, we have $\frac{DF}{AA'}=\frac 37$. Similarly, we have $\frac{DE}{DB'}=\frac 34$.

Hence, the result follows from these and $(1)$.

Comment: How did you know $(1)$ is true?

Comment: @JohnPart: For example, we have $\frac{[\triangle{AA'C}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}=\frac{A'C}{BC}$, right? (this is because the height is the same)Then, we have $\frac{[\triangle{A'B'A}]}{[\triangle{AA'C}]}=\frac{AB'}{AC}$.  I used this idea several times. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnPart: I added the details. Take a look.

Comment: I don't understand where the $$\frac{[\triangle{DEF}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}=\frac{[\triangle{ACA'}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}\times\frac{[AB'A']}{[\triangle{ACA'}]}\times\frac{[\triangle{DFB'}]}{[\triangle{AB'A'}]}\times\frac{[\triangle{DEF}]}{[\triangle{DFB'}]}$$ comes from though?

Comment: @JohnPart: Look at the right hand side. You'll see that the right hand side equals the left hand side. (you can cancel things.)

Comment: @JohnPart: To get $\frac{[\triangle{DEF}]}{[\triangle{ABC}]}$, I just considered smaller triangles : $ACA'\rightarrow AB'A'\rightarrow DFB'\rightarrow DEF$. This is the right hand side.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{A'C}{BC}$x$\frac{AB'}{AC}$ $\frac29$ though?

Comment: @JohnPart: $\frac{A'C}{BC}\times\frac{AB'}{AC}=\frac 23\times\frac 23=\frac 49$.

Comment: My diagram was wrong... Thanks so much for putting up with my sleep deprived brain!